# do while answer is outside of number range or not a number

Tags: javascript, nan, do-while

I created a simple `prompt` that allows a user to input a number between 1 and 10.  First I change `answer` from a string into a number.  Second I check to see if `answer` is between 1 and 10 or is `NaN`.  If `answer` is outside 1 and 10 or `NaN` the loop runs and checks again.  `while` correctly detects if numbers are less than 1 or greater than 10 however it doesn't properly detect if `answer == NaN`.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work with letters because the `alert` indicates that answer does = `NaN` when I input letters.  Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var answer;
 
do {
    answer = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 10.");
    answer = Number(answer);
}
while (answer < 1 || answer > 10 || answer == NaN);
 
alert(answer);
```

Comment: `NaN !== NaN`. Praise IEEE754. Use `Number.isNaN`. Else said, `answer == NaN` will **always** be false.

Comment: or just `isNaN` if you don't want to fail in internet exploder :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For detecting if answer is NaN, you can use the [isNaN()](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function.

## Update

As far as browser support, [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) is supported on all major browsers with the exception of **Internet Explorer**. The global [`isNaN()`](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function is supported on **IE**.

Answer (score 1):

In general, (although it doesn't make a difference here) it's better to use [`Number.isNan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) over [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). Hence, for best results try this:

```js
var _isNaN = Number.isNaN || isNaN;
var answer;

do {
    answer = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 10.");
    answer = parseInt(answer, 10);
} while (answer < 1 || answer > 10 || _isNaN(answer));

alert(answer);
```

Also, note that using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is better than using the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) constructor.

Comment: If you're targeting a Microsoft Browser, the [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) is only supported in ***Edge***, and not in ***Internet Explorer***.

Comment: Which is why we have the default set as `isNaN`. Also, please stop screaming.

Comment: Screaming means the usage of all CAPS; bold text is a mean for emphasizing a remark or comment... Don't be too sensitive.